# Passing params through jinja templates in SubDagOperator in Airflow 2

Tags: python-3.x, airflow, airflow-scheduler, airflow-2.x

**Airflow 2**: I have pushed an xcom from taskA and  I am pulling that xcom within subdag taskB. I have been unable to pull the necessary xcom. I was wondering how one would do this.

I was able to pull the necessary xcom with same piece of code in Airflow 1.10(additionally I was passing provide_context=True, is depricated in Airflow 2), but its failing in Airflow 2 with error message as:

`jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'DAG_ID' is undefined`

Code Below :

```
DAG_ID = 'test_dag_name' 
dag = DAG(
    DAG_ID,
    default_args=default_args, catchup=False,
    max_active_runs=1, schedule_interval=SCHEDULE_INTERVAL
)

with dag:
   test_bq = SubDagOperator(
    task_id='test_task_id',
    subdag=subdag_func(parent_dag_name=DAG_ID,
                                      child_dag_name='test_task_id',
                                      args=default_args,
                                      run_date=run_date,
                                      max_dt="{{ ti.xcom_pull(dag_id=DAG_ID ,task_ids='task_id_test')[0][0]}}"))
```

**Note :** If the exact dag name is passed in place of DAG_ID in xcom_pull, it works fine. But when passing the param(dag_id=DAG_ID),it fails.

Also, if xcom_pull(dag_id=None) as dag_id is optional from source code [link](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/models/taskinstance.py#L1524), new error pops up as :

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1166, in _run_raw_task
    self._prepare_and_execute_task_with_callbacks(context, task)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1248, in _prepare_and_execute_task_with_callbacks
    self.render_templates(context=context)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1761, in render_templates
    self.task.render_template_fields(context)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/baseoperator.py", line 997, in render_template_fields
    self._do_render_template_fields(self, self.template_fields, context, jinja_env, set())
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/baseoperator.py", line 1010, in _do_render_template_fields
    rendered_content = self.render_template(content, context, jinja_env, seen_oids)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/baseoperator.py", line 1047, in render_template
    return jinja_env.from_string(content).render(**context)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1090, in render
    self.environment.handle_exception()
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 832, in handle_exception
    reraise(*rewrite_traceback_stack(source=source))
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/_compat.py", line 28, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "<template>", line 68, in top-level template code
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/sandbox.py", line 384, in getitem
    return obj[argument]
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: None has no element 0```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to fix this issue by passing the parent dag name in a specified format :
`"{{ ti.xcom_pull(dag_id='" + DAG_ID + "',task_ids='task_id_test')[0][0] }}"` .
When passing `dag_id=DAG_ID`, parent dag name was not getting accessed but when passed as `dag_id='" + DAG_ID + "'`, resolved the issue.

Comment: SubDags are deprecated. You should change to TaskGroups

Comment: @Elad Thanks for the suggestion, But Regarding TaskGroup, it has a downside to its UI. Unlike other operators it does not provide "Clear", "Run" operations to run all the tasks underneath in one go , rather one has to clear, run each individual task. In our case we have multiple(> 15) task grouped together in one Subdag. Therefore, we cannot move towards TaskGroup for now